# Loading image code in the constructor work, the same code doesn't work from a button and a file chooser actions?

Tags: java, image, swing, load

I tried loading images, I found a code and it works well, the code for loading an Image is in the constructor,  I tried to move it to a [button](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JButton.html) action, and also to a [filechooser](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html). But never load an image. there are no errors in the code, and I tested the clauses using print statements, they show that the clauses are passed.

this is an SSCCE:

The constructor code is separated into two parts **Upper** and **Lower**. To demonstrate the problem **alternate** between these codes by commenting and uncommentting *each*.

the **Lower** part will work; it loads the image from the constructor.
the **upper** part set the JPanels and the JButtons required to load the image from Action code.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.imageio.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ImgLoadTest extends JPanel implements ActionListener
{

    File file;
    BufferedImage img;
    JButton fileChooserButton;
    JButton showImgButton;
    JPanel imgePanel;
    JPanel widgetPanel;
    JFileChooser fileChooser;

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        g.drawImage(img, 0, 60, null);
    }

    public ImgLoadTest()
    {
           //Upper:

//        fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
//
//        fileChooserButton = new JButton("Browse");
//        fileChooserButton.addActionListener(this);
//        showImgButton = new JButton("Show Image");
//        showImgButton.addActionListener(this);
//
//        imgePanel = new JPanel();
//        widgetPanel = new JPanel();
//        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
//        widgetPanel.add(fileChooserButton);
//        widgetPanel.add(showImgButton);
//        this.add(imgePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
//        this.add(widgetPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);


        /*
         *  try alternating (comment/uncomment) between 
         *  the upper code (in this constructor)
         *  and the lower code below;
         */

          //Lower:

        try
        {
            img = ImageIO.read(new File("D:\\De.JPG"));
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        Object source = e.getSource();
        if (source == fileChooserButton)
        {
            int reternedValue = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(ImgLoadTest.this);

            if (reternedValue == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
            {
                file = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
                try
                {
                    img = ImageIO.read(file);
                    System.out.println("File chooser: Image accepted");
                    this.repaint();

                } catch (IOException err)
                {
                    System.out.println("error " + err);
                }
            } else
            {
                System.out.println("No Image");
            }
        }
        if (source == showImgButton)
        {
            try
            {
                System.out.println("button: Image accepted");
                img = ImageIO.read(new File("D:\\De.JPG"));
                repaint();
            } catch (IOException err)
            {
                System.out.println("No Image");
                System.out.println("error " + err);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Image load test");
        frame.setSize(new Dimension(400, 600));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        ImgLoadTest imgLoadTest = new ImgLoadTest();
        frame.add(imgLoadTest);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: So, you add a bunch of components to a container, whose paintComponent method you've overridden to paint something onto he container...then wonder why the image won't appear...

Comment: Thanks for this point. I am not clever at that part of Java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just assigning the `BufferedImage` `img` will not make the image appear. You could add a `JLabel` which contains the image:

```
JLabel picLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(img));
imgePanel.add(picLabel);
imgePanel.revalidate();
imgePanel.repaint();
```

Answer (score 0):

Other than the fact that the paintComponent code should be done on the imgePanel, it should work. You might want to revalidate and repaint it( like Reimeus did) after assigning the new image, to make sure it actually gets painted on the screen.